# Unable to fetch Next.js Markdown blog cover image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, markdown

I am creating a static blog using Next.js. I have used `fs` and `gray-matter` packages to get the contents of Markdown files.

The directory structure is like -

```
my-blog
 -app
  -[slug]
   -page.js
 -contents
  -blogpost1
   -index.md
   -cover.png
  -blogpost2
   -index.md
   -cover.png
```

#### File [slug]/page.js

```js
<main>
 <h1>Title goes here</h1>
 <img src={`/contents/${post.data.slug}/cover.png`}/>
 <div>Content goes here</div>
</main>
```

I am unable to get the cover images using `localhost/contents/blogpost1/cover.png`.
I am new to Next.js. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: I see cover.md in your structure and you are having cover.png as a source

Comment: Sorry, it should be .png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static assets in Next.js served from the public folder and this folder cannot be updated. Once you build the app, only the images during the build time will be served.

You have two options:

1. Once you write the post, place the correct image in the public directory with  `dynamicSlug.png`. So in your dynamic route, you can get that image with

   "http://locahost/images/${slug}.png"
2. You set the metadata in Markdownlike this:

   ```
    ---
    title: "Markdown."
    coverImage: https://images.unsplash.com/whatever
    ---
   ```

You use a cover image from an external website. You need to configure `next.config.js`:

```
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: ["images.unsplash.com"]
  },

}
```

If you successfully parse the post Markdown content, you will have access to `post.coverImage`, so you can use it.